# How to open a hyperlink in a PDF from WKWebView

Tags: swift, pdf, webview, wkwebview

I am writing `Swift` 5, iOS14.4 and trying to open a PDF from in-app browser (WKWebView).

The PDF is this https://www.travelhealth.gov.hk/english/downloads/files/eHDF_poster_general.pdf

If I open the PDF in Safari as external browser, it works smoothly.
However when I use WKWebView oepn it in in-app browser, it doesn't response, nothing happens.

I try to prefix the pdf url with `docs.google.com/viewer?url=` the url in PDF becomes clickable, but when I click it, it shows me a blank page instead of the destination.